# zf2 module/global configuration

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2 and I do not understand the configuration of a ZF2 application.

For example the translation is configured in the module's config. In case of using modules from different sources, this seems a good way. But so I have to translate same things for each module - this is not a efficient way. 
Same for mail transportation. Normaly I want to send all mails of my web application on the same way (Sendmail or Smtp).

So is there a soluation to move this configuration from a module's config to the global config? Especially for using third party modules?

Regards
Bytecounter

Comment: All configs are merged in to one automatically, so there's no need to move configuration from one config file to another. What specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to set Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail as default mail tranpsorter globaly. But - for example look at the third party module ''phly/PhlyContact" - it configures it's own key '$config  = $config['phly_contact']['mail_transport'];. This is in case of autonomy a good idea, but not for comfortable configuration of a lot of modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just alias the service:

```
return [
    'service_manager' => [
        'aliases' => [
            'PhlyContactMailTransport' => 'MailTransport',
        ],
        'factories' => [
            'MailTransport' => function (ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                // create your transport

                return $transport;
            },
        ],
    ],
];
```

For reference, see

- https://github.com/phly/PhlyContact/blob/337cefe68214902e7a88f365c6c8601c6eee7e2b/config/module.config.php#L76
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html#sample-configuration

Comment: Thank's a lot! This is what I searched for.

Answer (score 0):

I have a global config for email in a folder `config/autoload/mail.global.php`

Like this

```
return [
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'MailTransport' => function ($sm) {
                $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\File();
                $options = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\FileOptions([
                    'path' => './data/mail',
                    'callback' => function (\Zend\Mail\Transport\File $transport) {
                        return 'Message_' . date('d_m_Y H_i') . '__' . mt_rand() . '.eml';
                    },
                ]);
                $transport->setOptions($options);

                return $transport;
            }
        ]
    ]
];
```

And call it anywhere `$this->getServiceManager()->get('MailTransport');`

Comment: Ok, but this won't work for third party modules which uses an own factory and config key. So I think, these modues are not 100% conform to ZF2.